# Change the order of a checkbox by click on a button - html css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code. At the moment when you click on a checkbox, it automatically moves to the top of the list.
I want to do this by clicking on a button.
By default the order is normal and when you click on the order button, the checked items should go to the top.

One approach would be using --var to change the value of order dynamically, but I could not implement it.

```css
div { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
label:has(input:checked) { order: -9999; }
```

```html
<h3>Topic</h3>
<div>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> q </label>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> w </label>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> e </label>
</div>
 <button id="alertButton">Click me</button>
<script>
    document.getElementById("alertButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
        
    });
</script>
```

Comment: please implement an example that reproduce the topic. So far the snippet doesn't do what you are talking about. Also where is the button? where is the js?

Comment: Assuming I'm interpreting the question correctly, I doubt this is possible with just CSS. However it would be a very small task in JS to apply an ever-decreasing `order` style each time a checkbox was selected.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some Javascript to toggle the order once you press a button.

Once way is to use `querySelectorAll()` to find all checked boxes, then `insertBefore` it on the second parent (to include the `label`).

Small demo, when you press `Click me`, the checked boxes will be places as first childs of the parent `div`.

```js
document.getElementById("alertButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    const checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
    checkedBoxes.forEach(b => {
        const parentDiv = b.parentNode.parentNode;
        parentDiv.insertBefore(b.parentNode, parentDiv.firstChild);
    });
});
```

```css
div { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
```

```html
<h3>Topic</h3>
<div>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> q </label>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> w </label>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> e </label>
</div>
<button id="alertButton">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

CSS Only :
Setting the default order for labels as 100 and everytime input is checked we are changing the order from 100 to 1.

```css
div { 
 display: flex; 
 flex-direction: column;
}
label{
 order:100;
}
label:has(input:checked) {
 order: 1; 
}
```

```html
<h3>Topic</h3>
<div>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> q </label>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> w </label>
  <label> <input type=checkbox> e </label>
</div>
 <button id="alertButton">Click me</button>
```

Comment: I think you misread a important line in OP's question: **I want to do this by clicking on a button.**